# Photo eye hysteresis

Tags: sensor

I am looking for some help here. I have a photo eye that controls a 120vac pilot relay which acts as an interposing relay to drive several high voltage lighting contactors throughout a plant.  Problem is: when the sun rises in the morning the photo eye's lack of a large deadband causes on/off chatter which effectively blinks light throughtout the whole plant. I was thinking an rc circuit in series withe the A1 of the pilot relay could help eliminate this chatter.  Any idea or suggestions would be appreciated. Also, is it possible that the coil on the pilot relay could have such a low impedence that it iscausing this hysteresis?

Comment: Do you have any manufacturer or model number information for the photo eye and the pilot relay? Or better yet, some links to information about them?

Answer (score 1):

I've always found it challenging to commingle industrial controls and discrete components, so I would suggest that you stay away from an RC filter even though it could be made to work.  Even ignoring regulatory issues, the simple packaging differences are a headache at best.

You didn't post specs to your photo sensor, but if your goal is simply to avoid flashing plant lighting around dawn, consider using a time delay relay (off-delay) between the sensor and your contactors to allow a "ride-through" period (really a resettable one-shot) -- ensuring that your plant lights stay on for a minimum period of time regardless of what the sensor's output is.

Off-delay relays are slightly different than a typical relay, as they require an uninterrupted pilot voltage in addition to the "coil terminals" -- the relay's input.

[image]

In this diagram, Input Voltage represents the pilot voltage - essentially the power supply to the time-delay relay, Initiate Switch would be the relay's signal input - coming from your photo sensor, and Load would be the plant lighting via the lighting contactors you already have.  Note how the load stays on after the Initiate Switch has gone low again.

In your application, the input will be high all night, so the output will remain on all night.  At dawn, when the sensor output tends to flap a bit, you'll ride through those transients as long as they are shorter than the off delay period.  The one downside of this approach is that the lights will stay on a little longer into the early morning than they otherwise might.

Such time delay relays can be purchased from McMaster-Carr or Grainger, and can also be very effectively coded in even the cheapest PLCs.  You'll still need the lighting contactors to carry the lighting load; time delay relays are typically used as pilot relays only.

Answer (score 0):

An RC circuit is unlikely to be useful in this case, and probably difficult to design given the voltage and current levels required.

What you really need is to add hysteresis to the photo eye. Assuming that it isn't possible or practical to modify its internal circuitry<sup>[1]</sup>, one easy way to accomplish this would be to have a small light that shines on the eye itself during the day. Does the pilot relay have a contact that's closed when the other contact (the one controlling the plant lights) is open? If so, you can wire your light to that. Otherwise, you might need to add one additional relay to control it.

<sup>[1]</sup> If it *is* possible that the photo eye could be modified, let us know! We can offer advice about that, too, and it would probably be the better overall solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used a photo-eye before, but if it is basically a light sensor, a way to add hysteresis would be to have it also turn on/off a relatively dim light that points to it (so it gets added to the ambient light being sensed when it turns on - deepening the on state, or subtracted when it turns off, deepening the off state).